# $.jQTouch.goTo is not a function Options

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I am trying to use the goTo function to rotate between images, here is 
my basic JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
          $.jQTouch(); 
          $(function () { 
            $('.touch').live('swipe', function (event, info) { 
              alert('called' + info.direction); 
              var id = $(this).parent().next().attr("id"); 
              alert(id); 
              $.jQTouch.goTo(id, 'slide'); 
            }); 
          }); 
 </script>
```

This works great up until I get to the $.jQTouch.goTo(id, 'slide');

line and then I get the following error:

```
$.jQTouch.goTo is not a function
```

How do I access this goTo function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgot to instantiate the var for me to use in my code - DOH!

```
   var jQT = new $.jQTouch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto is for switching between pages, not for image rotations. You'll have to write your own function for that. That's not where jQTouch is made for.

Comment: The image is in a different div that I want to slide in, I still need an answer to the question above